# Which time the calling thread gets object's intrinsic lock?

Tags: java, thread-safety

here is my class

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
        threadTest.m1();
        synchronized (threadTest) {
            threadTest.m2();
        }
        System.out.println("End of main thread");
    }

    public void m1() {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + i);
                }
                System.out.println("end of mythread");
            }
        });
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void m2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

Although i put my code inside `synchronized` block it doesn't seem to work properly and both of `for` loops are run parallelly.How can i run those loops as threadsafe in multi-threaded environment with a **synchronized block**.Where is the mistake i made my code given?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A synchronized block prevents other threads to enter the same or another synchonized block on the same object. You have a single synchronized block here, and only one thread enters it. So all the other threads can execute whatever they want.

Comment: +1 In short, each thread must have a synchronized block on the same object to see what the OP expects. You could make m2() synchronized and have thread in m1, call m2();

Comment: yes.i checked that.thanks JB and Peter for clean and quick reply :)